# French translations are not working in email templates in Magento2

Tags: magento2, email-templates, localisation

My email content is not translating to french, when admin user perform an action. We have **admin form** when user saved data we are triggering an email to the user. That respected email should be translate accordingly.

1. Created csv file and added required content & saved & deployed. **app/design/frontend/Demo/customtheme/i18n/fr_CA.csv**
2. When form submitting from admin end we are trigger an email here is the logic.

   ```
    $templateVariables = [
               'increment_id' => $order->getIncrementId(),
               'customer_name' => ucwords($order->getCustomerName()),
               'faceplates_url'  => '#'//will add url next
           ];
           $this->inlineTranslation->suspend();
           $senderEmail = $this->scopeConfig->getValue(self::SENDER_EMAIL, ScopeInterface::SCOPE_STORE, $order->getStoreId());
           $senderName  = $this->scopeConfig->getValue(self::SENDER_NAME, ScopeInterface::SCOPE_STORE, $order->getStoreId());
           $ccToSalesRepFlag = $this->scopeConfig->getValue(self::CC_TO_SALESREP_FLAG, ScopeInterface::SCOPE_STORE, $order->getStoreId());
           $postObject = new \Magento\Framework\DataObject();
           $postObject->setData($templateVariables);
           $transport = $this->transportBuilder
               ->setTemplateIdentifier(self::TEMPLATE)
               ->setTemplateOptions(['area' => \Magento\Framework\App\Area::AREA_FRONTEND, 'store' => $order->getStoreId()])
               ->setTemplateVars(['orderdata' => $postObject,'order_id' => $order->getId()])
               ->setFrom(['name' => $senderName,'email' => $senderEmail])
               ->addTo([$order->getCustomerEmail()]);
           if ($ccToSalesRepFlag == '1'):
               if ($order->getSalesRepresentativeEmail()):
                   $transport->addCC([$order->getSalesRepresentativeEmail()]);
               endif;
           endif;
           $transport->getTransport()->sendMessage();
           $this->inlineTranslation->resume();
   ```
3. app/code/Custom/Module/etc/email_templates.xml

   ```
   <?xml version="1.0"?>
   <config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNam espaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Email:etc/email_templates.xsd">
    <template id="violation_email" label="Email For Myorder" file="myorder.html" type="html" module="Custom_Module" area="frontend"/>
   </config>
   ```

Note: This email has been triggered when admin user saves the data from admin end.
& getting proper store id. Please advise.

Thanks in advance.